# Calculate the time complexity of recursion function

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I am seeking assistance in determining the time complexity of a given source code, which appears to be of the order O(n^3). Could someone kindly assist me in evaluating its time complexity?:

```
public static int function(int[] arr, int index) {

        if (index <= 0) {
            return arr[0];
        }

        int one = function(arr, index - 1);
        int two = function(arr, index - 2);
        int three = function(arr, index - 4);

        if (one > two) {
            return one;
        } else if (two > three) {
            return three;
        } else {
            return one;
        }
    }
```

I expecting that the time complexity is o(n^3)

Comment: It looks more like O(3^n) than O(n^3). In each recursion step, it calls itself 3 times. T(n) = 3 T(n-1), since it multiplies by 3 in each step, the order would be O(3^n).

Answer (score 0):

In each recursion step, the function calls itself three times, while reducing the index by substracting constant values.

Time for `index = n` would be:

```
T(n) = 3*T(n-1) = 3*3 T(n-2) ... ≅ 3*3...*3 T(0) = 3^n * T(0)
```

Which is exponential with base 3: O(3^n).